# Yii/PHP - How to Create Data Only Once?

Tags: php, yii

everyone. Just like my post, how to create a file only once?
Here's FileController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new File;
    if(isset($_POST['File']))
    {
        $simpan=$model->nama_file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'nama_file');
        if(empty($simpan)){
            $model->attributes=$_POST['File'];
            $model->save();
        }
        else{
        $model->attributes=$_POST['File'];
        $model->pengunggah=Yii::app()->user->id;
        $model->nama_file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'nama_file');
        if($model->save()){
            $simpan->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath .
                '/../files/' . $model->nama_file.'');
                //Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data berhasil disimpan!");
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_file));
        }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

After a user create a file, he/she cannot create another, it only allows user to create only once. How to implement it? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to ensure one user can create only one record, you need to check if a record associated with this user ID already exists before you process user input. `File::model()->exists(array('condition' => 'pengunggah = :userID', 'params' => array(':userID' => Yii::app()->user->id)))` can tell you if such a record exists.

Comment: okay thanks, where I should I put that code?

Comment: Add it to the model's `rules()` as a custom validator function.